# Using chart.js to output chart as a saved image rather than using canvas

Tags: chart.js

I am `chart.js` to create a chart and display it on the screen and this is fine.

Is it possible to get `chart.js` to output the chart as an image that can be saved without using canvas? The reason is that I would like to include the image in a pdf but do not want to have to see it on the screen first.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out the "dom-to-image" library?

Hope this helps!

[Dom-To-Image Library](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)

Comment: Thanks but the problem is I do not want any page to display, but simply have a pdf to download. This is great but as far as I can see requires the page to be displayed and then the DOM can be converted into png etc. Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: Your question stated that you 'do' want to see it on the screen first? I'm not sure on how to output the 'Rendered' chart element to an image/PDF file, without physically rendering it first.

here's another good example: [link](http://codepedia.info/convert-html-to-image-in-jquery-div-or-table-to-jpg-png/)

Comment: Ahhh sorry ... typing too quick for my own good. No I do not want to see it at all. I just want the image to be included into to the pdf without the on screen step.